# Problem While swf embedding in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

A problem that is waste my one hour
I am embedding swf in the flex application it works fine.

But when i embed one swf the compiler through an error

```
unable to resolve 'com/assets/swf/flash_ad.swf' for transcoding
Unable to transcode com/assets/swf/flash_ad.swf.
```

pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that swf is compiled and published in older version of action script.

So when i de-compile the swf and generate my own swf with latest version of action script the problem is gone.

Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your flex compiler is able to locate the swf first. Try refreshing your workspace, so compiler finds it.

Also ensure your swf is built correctly. Corrupted swf's wont get embedded.

Check if this helps: http://www.brightworks.com/flex_ability/?p=38